# What does the Axiom of Choice have to do with right inversibility?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I have encountered an exercise that asks to prove that, these two statements are equivalent:

1. every surjective function has a right inverse.
2. Axiom of choice.

Definition: Given a function $f$, we say that $f$ has a right inverse if there exists $g$ such that $f \circ g$ is the identity function.

I must admit, I can't see the connection...
Any help?

Thanks!
Shir

Comment: $g$ chooses an element of $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ for every $y \in \operatorname{Range}(f)$.

Comment: I've added "surjective" in 1. (otherwise it's obviously wrong).

Comment: @Martin: It's not wrong if you're a set theorist. Functions don't have an intrinsic codomain, and every function is onto its range. If your definition of a function includes a codomain (so $f(n)=n$ is a different function $\Bbb{N\to N}$ and $\Bbb{N\to R}$) then you are right.

Answer (score 5):

Note that if $f\colon A\to B$ is onto $B$ (and we can always take $B=\operatorname{rng}(f)$ for that), then $f^{-1}(b)$ is a non-empty set. Using the axiom of choice it is easy to construct an inverse.

On the other hand, if you have a family of disjoint sets, $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ then there is a function from $\bigcup A_i$ onto $I$, such that its inverse is exactly a choice function.